# Fastest way to distinct count a group based on another variable in the same line(distinct count of visitors to a page)

Tags: c#, data-structures, hashtable

I have a file containing two columns; visitorId and pageID. What I would like to find is number of unique/distinct visitors for every page. I am using HashTable in HashTable(dictionary) to track if that specific visitor has been counted or not for that speceific page. The file contains more than 1 Billion lines so performance is very critical. Is there any other data structure for counting distinct visitors other than HashTable in HashTable?

I have to solve this problem on files so importing to database is not an option. Development enviroment is .NET and language is C#.

You can find the code below:

```
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, bool>> dicVisitorCount = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, bool>>();
            Dictionary<int, int> dicPages = new Dictionary<int, int>();


            int million = 1000000;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10 * million; i++)
            {

                pageID = r.Next(1, 100000);
                visitorID = r.Next(1, 1000000);


                if (!dicPages.ContainsKey(pageID))
                {
                    dicPages.Add(pageID, 1);

                    Dictionary<int, bool> dicVisitors = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
                    dicVisitors.Add(visitorID, true);
                    dicVisitorCount.Add(pageID, dicVisitors);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!dicVisitorCount[pageID].ContainsKey(visitorID))
                    {
                        dicVisitorCount[pageID].Add(visitorID, true);
                        dicPages[pageID]++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think you'd be hard pressed to get performance out of 1 billion lines of anything.

Comment: Can't you just use the page ID as your index, and then add the visitors to one table/dictionary per page ID?

Comment: _"Is there any other data structure for counting distinct visitors"_ - of course. What does your current code look like and what are the actual problems with it (and please note "not performant" is not a problem)?

Comment: Does the file fit into memory? Does the unique visitor information you need fit into memory?

Comment: @Mario I can not use only pageID because pageID-visitorID couple makes it distinct. I tried concatenating 2 integers(pageID-visitorID) into 1 long but I did not get any performance improvement.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Both file and hashtable fit in memory. First I read all file into memory so reading the file is not an issue.

Comment: @Efe Think you misunderstood me. If I've got a table using the page IDs as indices and a list or whatever containing unique visitors to that page. You can then just pick any page ID and immediately get the number of unique visitors for it.

Comment: @Mario When reading a line, what I need immediately is if that specific visitor has been counted for that specific page. If I keep a list of visitors in a list It will take a long time to look up especially for pages with many visitors since I have to loop to the end of list.

Comment: @CodeCaster I added my code. Checking my dictionary in dictionary using ContainsKey and adding new items takes the most CPU time.

Comment: Can we assume anything about the ranges of the ID's?

Comment: @Dukeling pageIDs are around 100K and visitorIDs are around 1M. In real life the cardinality will be lower since most people views only a few popular pages.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I am reading and processing in blocks of 10M

Comment: @Efe Ah ok, so they don't all fit in memory at once. (PS I accidentally deleted my question about it fitting in memory!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a minor issue, I'd prefer a `Dictionary` of `int` to [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) as opposed to a `Dictionary` of `int` to `Dictionary` (the mapping functionality of a `Dictionary` is unnecessary here).

If you don't care about an exact result, a `Dictionary` of `int` to [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) could also be a consideration (with a separate count to keep track of how many elements are in each of the bloom filters).

Comment: HashSet is a better choice. Although I need exact answers bloom filters seems like a interesting option. Thank you.